# Handle a redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def new
  if @cart.line_items.empty?
    redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Your cart is empty'
    return
  end

  @order = Order.new
end
```

I have the following questions:

1. What happens when the controller executes the `redirect_to` statement? Does it pass the control to the store controller and it stops to execute the action `new` or not? Does it execute the `return` and `Order.new` statements?
2. What is the goal of the `return` statement here?

Comment: You can write first 4 lines into one `return redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Your cart is empty' if @cart.line_items.empty?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_to` just a method call. It notes the desire of the controller action to emit an HTTP 302 (instead of rendering some view) after the action is completed. After the `redirect_to` method returns, the action continues to execute, it thus doesn't pass the control flow away completely.

Because of that, you need to use `return` here to stop the execution of the action after you scheduled the redirect in `redirect_to`. If you would have omit the `return`, the `Order.new` statement would have been executed before the redirect occurred.

Answer (score 1):

- What happens when the controller executes the redirect_to statement?

It triggers a new request to your webserver

- Does it pass the control to the store controller and it stops to execute the action new or not?

it doesnt pass from controller to controller, it tells the browser to go to another controller. So its not internal to your app.

- Does it execute the return and Order.new statements?

redirection happens once your controller reaches `return` everything after is not touched

- What is the goal of the return statement here?

You have to explicitly tell the controller that you're done in this case

Comment: if I do not explicit the `return` statement what happens?

Comment: then if I do not explicit `return` is `Order.new` executed?

Comment: No it won't execute..because your control now goes to store

Comment: yes it will execute `Order.new` if you skip the `return` command

Comment: even if condition is true and return is removed

Comment: @rubyist And that's where you are wrong. The code after a `redirect_to` will ALWAYS be executed (unless `redirect_to` throws an exception). That's why you typically need to put a return after the `redirect_to`.

Comment: Thanks Guys...for giving me clear understanding about redirect_to

Answer (score 0):

redirect_to

- triggers a new request to your webserver

Return

- If you put explicit return then it allows you to break out early and do not execute whatever you have return after your return keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this

```
def new
   return redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Your cart is empty' if @cart.line_items.empty?
   @order = Order.new 
end
```